# Cannot set style for label inside css

Tags: html, css

I have a html code:

```
<div class="projLeader">
<div class="ui-widget-content">
<label>Captain:</label>
<ol>
    <li class="placeholder" name="projLeader"><div class="adding">Drop Here</div></li>
    <li class="dropClass" name="projLeader"  <?php if (isset($projLeader)) echo 'value="'.$projLeader.'"' ?>><?php echo "<span class='closer'>x</span>".$projLeader.""?></li>
    <input type="hidden" name="projLeader" class="hiddenListInput1" />
</ol>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to add css style:

```
.projLeader label
{
    margin-left:25% !important;
}
```

But it does not work. if i put it inside label in html code it works:

```
<label style:'margin-left:25%;'>Captain:</label>
```

I have style for `.projLeader`:

```
.projLeader
{
    float:left;
    margin:3px;
    width:30%;  
}
```

And it works, so why it does not work with label?

Comment: please consider creating a http://jsfiddle.net to eliminate the chance you have conflicting styles from elsewhere in your stylesheet/an external stylesheet

Comment: I created a JSFiddle of your scenario: https://jsfiddle.net/48mav0kn/
Could you please update it with your missing styles as at least for now it appears the styles are being applied correctly...

Comment: @FiringSquadWitness im using foundation.css not sure how can include it there

Comment: @haxxxton https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/97u0peju/233/ check the fiddle

Comment: @FiringSquadWitness https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/97u0peju/233/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as it looks this will probably work

```
.projLeader label
{
    margin-left: 25% !important;
}
```

but consider this if **.ui-widget-content** has it's own selector for label in its CSS then your style will be denied. To give your style priority add the exact same selector **.ui-widget-content** **Try to use inspect element to see what it used as a selector** used and put your override CSS below that library.

```
.projLeader .ui-widget-content label
{
    margin-left: 25% !important;
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: It didnt help. I tried to remove every stylesheet i had but still it did not work

Comment: I cannot assume what is going on but if put a style that should be workint but did not it means some sort of override css is happening somewhere and you need to remove it to make it work. I need to see a working example to see what is going on.

Comment: now i got it even weirder. I removed ALL stylesheets, and left only one where i include only one line of css: which is `.projLeader label
{
    margin-left: 25% !important;
} `  I removed `.ui-widget-content` also. And the weirdest thing html page still shows some style from styleshhet. But it is EMPTY, only one line. How is it possible.

Comment: [Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/97u0peju/234/) Its working here

Comment: I actually checked your fiddle and put **.projLeader label { margin-left: 25% !important; }** at the bottom of the css file and it works. So most probably in your site there is a css selector somewhere that modifies your output. Also make sure to clear cache your browser when changing CSS it might have just cached

Comment: I got it worked by changing name of stylesheet. I am confused. I have only one createProject.css which i am using on different html pages but same css. Now when removed all styles inside stylesheet page still was using style from that stylesheet even it was empty, so assumed it used another stylesheet  which i was not actually modifying. Then i changed name to createProject2.css and it works now

Comment: In that case the old stylesheet might be caching in the first place. Tp prevent browser from caching your stylesheet when you have created some changes consider doing something like this **<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?t=123123123123** where **t=value** is a timestamp. So every time you update change the value with the current timestamp

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy, @preenz has made a great suggestion about cacheclearing, as it appears you're using PHP you could use something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?t=<?php echo time(); ?>" />` just remember that this should only really be used in development, and should be removed before production